Optimal data structure for assembling data in Python
I'm doing a calculation over 1M+ records, that's not individually intensive (ie, <<1s to complete a single calc) but in aggregate, is quite sluggish (only ~1000 data points produced per second).  I'm wondering if the use of a list/append statement to create the output time series could be improved here (or, perhaps the obvious, this is just a non-trivial calculation so will take a while)?  I've already utilized matrix multiplication as best as possible, so not sure how else this could be sped up.  Data samples referenced below as well.
import numpy as np

    tlfv = []
    for i, (la,lb) in enumerate(zip(LA,LB)):
        
        _ =  lvl_b.iloc[i,lb] + \
                       np.multiply(lvl_b.iloc[i,:] - lvl_b.iloc[i,lb], bk_b.iloc[i,:]).loc[(lvl_b.iloc[i,:] - lvl_b.iloc[i,lb])>0].sum() + \
                           lvl_a.iloc[i,la] + \
                               np.multiply(lvl_a.iloc[i,:] - lvl_a.iloc[i,la], bk_a.iloc[i,:]).loc[(lvl_a.iloc[i,la] - lvl_a.iloc[i,:])>0].sum()
    
        tlfv.append(_)

lvl_a -- [1.2M x 10] matrix
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
38  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
39  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
40  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
41  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
42  4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25
43  4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25
44  4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25

lvl_b -- [1.2M x 10] matrix
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
18  4487.0  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75
19  4487.0  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75
20  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75 4484.5
21  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75 4484.5
22  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75 4484.5
23  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75 4484.5
24  4487.0  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75
25  4487.0  4486.75 4486.5  4486.25 4486.0  4485.75 4485.5  4485.25 4485.0  4484.75

LA -- [1.2M x 1] vector
    0
16  7
17  7
18  6
19  7
20  7
21  7
22  7
23  6
24  6
25  6

LB -- [1.2M x 1] vector
    0
18  4
19  4
20  3
21  3
22  3
23  3
24  4
25  4
26  4

bk_a -- [1.2M x 10] matrix
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    9   6   17  14  16  15  17  14  17  28  30
    10  6   17  14  16  15  16  14  17  28  30
    11  6   17  14  16  15  16  14  17  28  30
    12  6   17  14  16  15  16  14  17  28  30
    13  6   17  14  16  15  16  14  17  28  30
    14  7   17  14  16  15  16  14  17  28  30
    15  7   17  14  16  15  16  14  27  28  30
    16  5   17  14  16  15  16  14  27  28  30

bk_b -- [1.2M x 10] matrix
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
22  26  28  34  34  62  39  45  46  28  23
23  26  28  34  34  62  39  45  46  28  23
24  2   26  28  34  34  62  39  45  46  28
25  2   24  28  34  34  62  39  45  46  28
26  2   24  29  34  34  62  39  45  46  28
27  2   24  29  34  35  62  39  45  46  28
28  2   24  29  34  35  62  40  45  46  28
29  2   24  29  34  35  62  40  46  46  28

tlfv output -- [1.2M x 1] vector

You can preallocate the array to the size you need it via something like tlfv = [None] * len(LA), this will reduce the array resizing calls under the hood when trying to append of a list.

Can you add the output of a runtime profiler, such that we better understand which operations actually consume the majority of the runtime?
